# Having access issues with factory method objects in HashMap

Tags: java, methods, hashmap

I am having compiler issues with the syntax and want this method to work on the `Hashmap` object `myMap`.  I need the `Add` method to take a `String` value and use the `Hashmap` `put` function to add a (key, value) pair.

I tried to put the factory method initiation of `newMap` inside `main` and had access issues.

```
 import java.util.*;

  public class MyMap {

  public static String item;
  public static String brand;

  Map<String, String> myMap = newMap();

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    myMap.Add("apple");   

   }

   public static HashMap<String, String> newMap() {
   return new HashMap<>(); 
    } 

   public static void Add(String item)  {
    String brand = "nobrand";
    myMap.put(item, brand);
  }   


}
```

compilation error due to static/non static items.  I made them all static to make everything accessible throughout the class.

Comment: `static Map<String, String> myMap` ?

Comment: Looks like you're running into a problem that a lot of beginner java programmers hit: what the `static` keyword really means. Off-site tutorials are probably a better resource for this concept.

Comment: My research has told me that static makes the item accessible to the class instead of just the instance of the class.

Comment: @CodeNewb and you try to access nonstatic `myMap` from static context of `add`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two mistakes:

First you should make `myMap` static like this:

```
static Map<String, String> myMap = newMap();
```

Second you should change  `myMap.Add("apple");`   to `Add("apple");`  because you write a method for main class not for `HashMap` that you expect to call it like that and also `Add` method is static and has access to `myMap` .

Total class would be like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    public static String item;
    public static String brand;

    static Map<String, String> myMap = newMap();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Add("apple");

    }

    public static HashMap<String, String> newMap() {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }

    public static void Add(String item) {
        String brand = "nobrand";
        myMap.put(item, brand);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm still getting a compilation error  error: non-static method Add(String) cannot be referenced from a static context
    Add("apple");  I took out the static keyword in the Add function declaration

Comment: @CodeNewb ok I will add total class for you and check it

Answer (score 1):

I agree with all @Spara answer

I would like to give a little more help

```
package com.goriant.stackoverflow.answers;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyMap {

    private static final String DEFAULT_BRAND = "no_brand";
    /**
    * item - brand Map
    */
    private Map<String, String> brandMap;

    /**
    * constructor
    */
    public MyMap() {
        this.brandMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    /**
    * add item with default brand
    * @param item
    */
    public void addItem(final String item) {
        this.brandMap.put(item, DEFAULT_BRAND);
    }

    /**
    * get brand by item
    * @param item
    * @return brand or null if there is no item in brandMap
    */
    public String getBrandByItem(final String item) {
        return this.brandMap.get(item);
    }

    /**
    * This is using for testing MyMap class
    * @param args
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // init MyMap - final is my habit :)
        final MyMap myMap = new MyMap();

        // add apple with default no_brand
        myMap.addItem("apple");

        // assert that your brand item is nobrand
        assert myMap.getBrandByItem("apple") == DEFAULT_BRAND;
    }
}
```

**Revise at 2022-03-01**

If you run this class with Java version <14, please pass flag to enable assertion feature

`java -ea com.goriant.stackoverflow.answers.MyMap`

You can refer github source code here: https://github.com/goriant-com/stackoverflow/blob/master/src/main/java/com/goriant/stackoverflow/answers/MyMap.java